# Better way than using multiple flattens?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

I am running some calculations with vectors (lists) and in order to perform them, they need to be flattened. Is there a better or neater way to do this?

```
ReactionPower = Flatten[RF1].Flatten[RF1vel] + Flatten[RF2].Flatten[RF2vel];
```

All the variables are of the form:

```
RF1 = {{x},{y}}
```

x and y are not integers, but long expressions with trigonometric functions.

Comment: What do `RF1`, `RF1vel`, `RF2`, and `RF2vel` look like before `Flatten[]`-ing?

Comment: @J.M. All are of the form {{ }, { }}

Comment: Ah, so `ReactionPower` is a scalar?

Comment: @J.M. Correct and the variables on the RHS are x and y components

Comment: Maybe a route that is "better ... than using multiple `Flatten[]`s..." can be had if you modify the process generating those lists to be `Flatten[]`-ed.

Comment: @J.M. I agree, I was just hoping to avoid rewriting sections of the code to accommodate the lists in an unflattened condition.

Comment: It would be helpful to see sample variables that show the unflattened shapes.  For example, if the unflattened lists are not ragged then solutions may include things like `Total[rf1*rf1vel + rf2*rf2vel, 2]` or `Total[{rf1*rf1vel, rf2*rf2vel}, 3]`.

Comment: @WReach the form of the variables is in the comments, I'll make an edit to the question

Answer (score 6):

Given:

```
rf1 = {{x1}, {y1}};
rf2 = {{x2}, {y2}};
rf1vel = {{vx1}, {vy1}};
rf2vel = {{vx2}, {vy2}};
```

Here is a way using `Total`:

```
reactionPower = Total[rf1*rf1vel + rf2*rf2vel, 2]
(* vx1 x1 + vx2 x2 + vy1 y1 + vy2 y2 *)

reactionPower === Flatten[rf1].Flatten[rf1vel] + Flatten[rf2].Flatten[rf2vel]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will certainly be less efficient, but is slightly shorter:

```
ReactionPower = Tr[RF1.Transpose[RF1vel] + RF2.Transpose[RF2vel]];
```